# Python iterator and iterable with list

Tags: python

I'm learning Python by watching a Pluralsight [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=python-fundamentals) and started to experiment with a iterator and iterable example. One issue I ran into that I can't explain is the following iterator and iterable example:

The following either returns the first item or raises a ValueError if empty:

```
def first(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        return next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("iterable is empty")
```

The example in the course worked:

```
first({"1st","2nd","3rd"})
```

by returning **'1st'** but when I changed the content of the list to:

```
first({"1","2","3"})
```

The value returned was **'2'** instead of '1'

Why is this occurring?

BTW, I also tried:

```
first({1,2,3})
```

and that returns the expected value of: **1**

Comment: That has nothing to do with iterators. `sets` are unordered in python. The first element the iterator picks off could be anything.

Comment: Take any course that assumes or implies that a set has a "first" element with a grain of salt.

Comment: That is my bad, the course example had it right in the video, but when I coded the example I used {} instead of []. The interesting question is if the first() function should check if is a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not working with `list`s at all. `{"1st","2nd","3rd"}` is a `set` literal, and `set`s are unordered (they iterate in *some* order, but not a useful order, or even necessarily repeatable order across different runs of Python or `set`s constructed in different ways within a single run of Python).

If you're trying to make a `list` literal, use `[]`, not `{}`. `first(["1st","2nd","3rd"])`, `first(["1","2","3"])` and `first([1,2,3])` will all behave predictably (returning `"1st"`, `"1"` and `1` respectively), as `list`s have ordering.

Comment: Ahh, that is what I was missing, Thanks!